# MBRContains distance from location help MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, geospatial

Ok so I am new to the **MBRContains** method and having trouble getting a method to work. Basically I am just trying to filter listings dependent on distance away from an input location.

---

I heard this method is quicker than just doing the complex math calculations. Please correct me if im wrong.

---

I havent been able to get this work as of yet, and was hoping for someone to just explain how it works as well as fix this code.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    listings JOIN suburbs ON listings.suburb_id = suburbs.id
WHERE   MBRContains
  (
    LineString
      (
         Point (
           @lon + 10 / ( 111.1 / COS(RADIANS(@lat))),
           @lat + 10 / 111.1
         ),
         Point (
           @lon - 10 / ( 111.1 / COS(RADIANS(@lat))),
           @lat - 10 / 111.1
         ) 
       ),
       LineString(
         Point(
           suburbs.longitude / ( 111.1 / COS(RADIANS(suburbs.latitude))),
            suburbs.latitude / 111.1
         )
      ) 
   )
```

I got this code from another question but i havent been able to understand it or work it out. Well actually they had **point** where I have my second **LIneString**. however i have my **lat** and **lng** stored in their own columns.

---

I want to transform this code into a function, say *WITHINDISTANCE* function which I will call instead of that big bunch of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `MBRContains()` is to exploit a [MySQL geospatial index](http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/using-mysqls-geospatial-extension-location-finder/). When you have `lat` and `lng` in their own columns, `MBRContains()` won't help performance at all.

But you can do bounding-rectangle calculations directly with your column values. When you do that, you use the `BETWEEN` operator to find appropriate rows. That operator works very well indeed with MySQL indexes, because it can do index range scans.

You can use SQL like this.

```
@lat := --the latitude of your point;
@lng := --the longitude of your point;
@radius := 10;
@distance_unit = 111.1;

WHERE suburbs.latitude
     BETWEEN @lat  - (@radius / @distance_unit)
         AND @lat  + (@radius / @distance_unit)
AND suburbs.longitude
 BETWEEN @lng - (@radius / (@distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(@lat))))
     AND @lng + (@radius / (@distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(@lat))))
```

It looks messy, but it does a straightforward bounding box calculation, then index scans on your latitude and longitude columns.

Here's a complete writeup of how to do this.
http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/

Comment: ah ok. this is quite nice. So is it better to store location data as lat and lng in the one column?